# cx_Oracle: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option for alter session command

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I am currently trying to run the following command from within my python program using cx_Oracle:

`alter session set "_use_nosegment_indexes" = true;`

I am trying to write a program for a university project that can be used for index tuning and need to be able to run explain plans from within the program (which is working fine) that take into account virtual indexes. From my understanding, the above needs to be set in order for this to happen but i get the following error in python:

`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`

This is all being done over a connection to the remote server that Oracle is running on. Am i doing something wrong or is this something that is not supported by cx_Oracle, in which case is there another package i could use where i can do this. If not, is there another DBMS that i could try this on where explain plans for virtual indexes can be run from within a python program.

Thanks

Comment: What if you execute directly from sqlplus?

Comment: @OldProgrammer The command executes fine using sqlplus

Comment: Then you have a formatting problem with your string - maybe the double quotes?  I don't know python.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have tried in sqlplus with no quotes and single quotes and the only thing that is accepted is double quotes so that is why I'm doing it the same in python.

I have finally found the issue and it was because i was using single quotes around the rest of it. Not sure why this should affect it but the final query looked like this:

`"alter session set \"_use_nosegment_indexes\" = true"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the right combination of single quotes and double quotes. In the end the code that worked was:

```
query = "alter session set \"_use_nosegment_indexes\" = true"
dbcursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this (it's a bit clearer):

```
query = """alter session set "_use_nosegment_indexes" = true"""
dbcursor.execute(query)
```